# C# Application process hangs after some time

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, process

I implemented a simple C# application which inserts about 350000 records into the database. This used to work well and the process took approximately 20 minutes.

I created a progress bar which lets you know approximately the progress of the records insertion. When the progress bar reaches about 75% it stops progressing. I have to manually terminate the program as the process doesn't seem to complete. If I use less data (like 10000), the progress bar finishes and the process is completed. However when I try to insert all the records, this won't happen any more.

Note that if I wait longer to terminate the program manually, more records would have been inserted. For example, if I terminate the program after 15 minutes, 200000 records are inserted, whereas if I terminate the program after 20 minutes, 250000 records are inserted.

This program is using a single thread. In face I can't do anything else until the process is complete. Does this have anything to do with threading or processes?

Any feedback will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your code, like an exception is swallowed silently or something similar. You mind sharing the code with us?

Comment: Any feedback would be greatly appreciated... too, at least for other people facing similar problems if not for the curiosity of those who took their time to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is surprising that your progress bar works at all. If you don't use a separate thread then your long running task will stop the message loop from running, causing your application to be unresponsive.

You should run this task using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). Put your long-running code inside a handler for the [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) event. Use [ReportProgess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.reportprogress.aspx) to update the progress bar. Don't access form controls directly from inside the DoWork handler.

There are some examples of how to do it on MSDN.

Also, make sure that you don't update the progress bar for every single change. If you have 100,000 records, only update the progress bar for every 100 or 1000 records, for example. Too many events can also cause the program to stop responding.

Comment: The application is singlethreaded, how on earth would the problem be related to multithreading issues?

Comment: @Jorge, if the application is on a single thread the insert code will be chewing up all the resources. So callback to the UI would be limited (if any)

Comment: @Jorge: Yes, his application is single threaded and that explains why the progress bar doesn't work. I've updated the answer to explain this more clearly.

Comment: how would you explain that the hangup appears only after some time? If not running in the background was the real issue, it would hang immediately, don't you think?

Comment: @Marek: That is why I wrote 'surprising' ;) My best guess is that he is splitting the action into smaller chunks so that the event loop gets some running time, but not as much as it needs to keep up. If he is updating the progress bar for every single change instead of bulking for example. Actually I will add that to my answer. :)

Comment: I'm assuming the code is something like: loop --> insert 500 records, update progress bar and that won't kill the progress (altough it could get you a "non responding" message...

Answer (score 2):

If you insert a lot of records, try to use bulk copy. It will dramatically raise the speed of your application.
These functions are quite straightforward, you put all your records to be inserted in a datable (with the same schema as the destination table) and call the function with it.

To grab the datatable schema if you're lazy just make a query like "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE 0=1", the resultset will only contain the tablename schema.

```
    private static void InsertTable(DataTable dt)
    {
        dt.AcceptChanges();

        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ToString()))
            {
                //Destination Table is the same as the source.
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = dt.TableName;
                try
                {
                    // Write from the source to the destination.
                    bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                } 
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write(ex.Message);
                }
            }


    }
    private static void InsertTableWithIdentity(DataTable dt)
    {
        dt.AcceptChanges();

        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ToString(), SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity))
        {
            //Destination Table is the same as the source.
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = dt.TableName;
            try
            {
                // Write from the source to the destination.
                bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

As for why it slows down, it's simple, the time it takes for a query to execute increases exponentially with the number of records. Because it stores in memory the future state of the database and only write it after the commit (in your case the end of the transaction) so use bulkcopy of simply put some more commits.

Comment: Instead of having a huge SQL query, split it in batches, my trials and errors tests were batches of about 500 inserts were ok.
SqlExec(myquery1);
SqlExec(myquery2); etc etc.

Comment: Wasn't it about a MySQL database?

Comment: Oh right, did'nt see the mysql tag, forget about the bulk copy then.
But for the rest it's the same try to split your big query in smaller queries.
If it's already the case, then check if you're reusing the same mysql connection between queries, or at least disposing the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

How are you treating exceptions during the process of insertion?

What kind of data are you inserting? Could it be generating an exception?

Answer (score 0):

You should run your insertion on a separate thread with the option to cancel the operation (rather than forcing shutdown). As suggested by @Mark using something like a BackgroundWorker or just create a separate thread and take a note of it. It seems as though the process is bottlenecking at somepoint you should perhaps look at doing some logging.

Answer (score 0):

Not related to the progress thing, but are you commiting batches of inserts? This might speed up the process quite a lot (and reduce resources consumption).

Answer (score 0):

Facts:

- you state that it hangs while a few lines after that you state that the application is still processing something and the later you terminate it, the more items are actually processed before it is killed.

Not easy to tell what the problem is without any source code, but I would suspect a slow down due to a memory leak or other performance degradation factor.

A few guesses:

- Are you closing/disposing all your no longer needed database connections? Undisposed database connections can create huge memory leaks and hang the application.
- Have you tried running the application in a memory/performance profiler? (ANTS is great)
- Have you tried attaching a debugger to the application after some time to see where exactly it hangs and whether it hangs at all?

Answer (score 0):

First, create a function that changes the Progress Bar, then add a delegate for that function.  Create another thread to update the progress bar.  It should look like this when you're done.

```
private delegate void UpdateProgressBarDelegate();

private void UpdateProgressBar()
{
     if (this.progressBar1.InvokeRequired)
     {
         this.progressBar1.Invoke(new UpdateProgressBarDelegate(UpdateProgressBar));
     }
     else
     {
         //code to update progress bar
     }    
}
```

If you need to include any parameters, you would do so like this:

```
this.progressBar1.Invoke(new UpdateProgressBarDelegate(UpdateProgressBar), param1, param2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use threads for these kind of stuff.

somewhere in my code:

```
// Definition 
private static Thread TH;
```

....

```
// When process starts
TH = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Splash_MyCallBack)); 
TH.Start();
```

....

```
// This method starts the form that shows progress and other data
static private void Splash_MyCallBack()
{
   frmLoading FL;

   FL = new frmLoading();

   FL.ShowDialog();

} /* Splash_MyCallBack*/

// Your process calls Splash_Stop when it is done.
static public void Splash_Stop()
{
   TH.Abort();
} /* Splash_Stop*/
```

frmLoading performs the visual stuff, while in the background I have a very processor-intensive task.
My process reports to an interface its progress. frmLoading implements that interface so it is aware of it and can show whaever it is needed (2 progress bars in my case)
Tha only catch is, frmLoading must have this in the constructor:

```
Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls= false;
```

which may be risky in some scenarios (not my case).

Hope this helps, I can add more stuff if you like.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

There wasn't a problem after all. The problem was that I was using a virtual machine and therefore it was a bit slow. When I ran this on a Xeon server, the process got completed in about 10 minutes.

Comment: I would still follow Mark Byers' advice on the BackgroundWorker. Putting long running tasks with your GUI code = A Very Bad Idea. And besides, the extra effort involved in this case would be minimal.